# my controller extends app_controller $components and $html helpers natively?

Tags: cakephp, authentication, components

I have my UsersController which of course extends my app_controller.

In my app_controller I have my $components defined as such:

```
$components = array('Acl', 'Auth', 'Session', 'RequestHandler');
```

When I try to access my users index view, I get an error (which means that the Auth component has not been activated in the controller).

BUT

If I place this line direct in my UsersController:

```
$components = array('Acl', 'Auth', 'Session', 'RequestHandler');
```

The page works as expected.

My remote server has the latter issue. But my local dev environment seems to extend the $components from the app_controller just fine.

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Here is my app_controller source code:

```
class AppController extends Controller {

var $helpers = array('Html', 'Form', 'Session', 'Ajax', 'Javascript');   
var $components = array('Auth', 'Acl', 'Session', 'RequestHandler'); 

function beforeFilter() {
    //Configure AuthComponent  
    $this->Auth->authorize = 'actions';
    $this->Auth->loginRedirect = array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'cms');
    $this->Auth->logoutRedirect = array(Configure::read('Routing.admin') => false, 'controller' =>       'users', 'action' => 'logout');
    $this->Auth->actionPath = 'controllers/';
    $this->Auth->allow('display'); // Allows all action =>  pages for non logged in users.
 }
}
```

Comment: can you paste your app_controller code? cake merges values by default so you are maybe doing something funny in __construct in one of the controllers

Comment: I added my app_controller code above : )

Comment: Do you use `beforeFilter` in your Users controller as well? And if so: do you call `parent::beforeFilter()` from within that callback?

Comment: harpax, yes I did try that earlier today. That was one suggestion I found online earlier. It's got to be a php or apache config setting difference in relation to Objects Inheritance would be my guess. Still searching...

Comment: if you use beforeFilter() in the OtherController you need to call parent::beforeFilter() or things break

Comment: This is exactly what I tried:  function beforeFilter() 
        { 
                parent::beforeFilter();AppController::beforeFilter() 

        }

Comment: OldWest, you don't need to specify `AppController::beforeFilter()` in the `OtherController`

Comment: Please add the code for your `OtherController`

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem like this a way back (but I thought it had been fixed). Cake was sensitive to the order of 'Auth' & 'Acl' in the components declaration. Try swapping them round. I see in your two code samples they *are* swapped.